# How to install Jmeter on Gitlab runner machine?

Tags: jmeter, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am new to using JMeter with GitLab CI/CD. I have created loadTest suite and want to configure it in Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. I have run.sh file in my loadTest project which do following:

1. Create and set up test data
2. Download JMeter dependencies and plugins (if JMeter already exists, skip this step)
3. Run the test
4. Clean up test data

Questions:

1. Is it a good idea to download JMeter in your project folder while you run the script or use      JMeter docker image and run the tests ? I am concern about keeping JMeter folder in GitLab repo and occupying unnecessary space.
2. How to install Jmeter on Gitlab runner machine ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your `run.sh` script downloads JMeter you don't need to put JMeter into Github repo. Using Docker is [also possible](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html), you can either [check existing images](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=jmeter) or [create your own](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-docker) with your own test data and plugins.
2. Gitlab runners are normal Linux machines (if you choose the [relevant executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/)), my expectation is that your `run.sh` should work just fine there as it is (or with minimal amendments, like installing Java prior to installing JMeter)